# Using discriminates with/without against

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, sentence-construction

I am not sure if discriminate should always followed by against? 
Example:

> .. and discriminates against its users in terms of ..

Or,

> .. and discriminates its users in terms of ..

Comment: It's quite possible to *discriminate* ***in favour of*** someone too. (*In hiring the best person for the job, I discriminated **in favour of** my cousin.*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The word **discriminate** has two meanings. The [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/discriminate) has:
>
> **discriminate**
>   VERB
>   [no object]
>
> **1** Recognize a distinction; differentiate.
>
> *babies can discriminate between different facial expressions*
>
> **2** Make an unjust or prejudicial distinction in the treatment of different categories of people, especially on the grounds of race, sex, or age.
>
> *existing employment policies discriminate against women*

So your example sentences need more context, to see what they are actually saying.

Comment: It is the second meaning.

Comment: I hope the dictionary definitions help you to phrase the sentence correctly. The second one includes the word "against", the first does not. Your two examples are in the opposite sequence.